# Can you use electricity if it causes global warming?

Tags: halal-haram, technology

I want to ask that can I use electronics and electricity if electricity causes global warming and  global warming causes harm to people. Is it a sin to use electricity then? Does it count as murder if the pollution you made end up killing someone?

Comment: If we stop using electricity we might not even survive nowadays! So it has become a must which we can't just give up, and therefore we can use it, but we might be able to say hey I want clean energy,like electricty out of wind or solar energy instead of other options!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a sin.  Of course it's a thing that you should follow from your "Marja" (Frankly speaking, he is a man who knows Islam better than us and people choose and follow him, and respect his opinions about the matters). But, as i know, none of them consider this as a sin.  (They use electricity themselves...)

Another logical reason is this:
At the time of Muhammad, There were horses. They rode horses and this caused air pollution. The air pollution could cause harm to people. So, should Muhammad and all his followers not use horses? He used it himself! So, This is not a good reason for not using the technology.

The third reason which came to my mind is:

There is a story from Muhammad... Someday he heard that another country has made a real good weapon. He instantly commanded to buy that weapon for the Army of Islam. The reason is clear. How could you fight an enemy which has better weapons than you do? So, the weapons may cause harm to people. But there is a greater good in buying them and using them by the Army of Islam.